# Another Rebus puzzle

Tags: english, rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
  I I
  I I I
  I I I I
___________

   O   O
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I love rebus puzzles!! That one is

> "Os under the Is" = **"circles under the eyes"**

Comment: Can you provide a (hidden) explanation of how you got to that answer? I'm new to rebus puzzles and I'd like to know your thought process.

Answer (score 9):

Is it:

> Glasses? Two eyes, three eyes, four eyes. Four eyes = glasses = O   O